# Javascript function to create Firebase CustomToken

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm creating a custom TamperMonkey script for Firebase in order to do some local testing on my website
Inserting the UID of a given FireBase Authentication User I create a [customToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) for it.

Here is my current code

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         my-name
// @namespace    my-namespace
// @version      1.0
// @author       Myself
// @match        XXXX-my-website-XXXX
// @require      https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.2/firebase-app.js
// @require      https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.2/firebase-auth.js
// @require      https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/hmac-sha256.js
// @require      https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/components/enc-base64-min.js
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    function generateCustomToken(uid) {
        if(typeof CryptoJS === undefined) {
            alert("CryptoJS not found");
            return;
        }

        // https://console.firebase.google.com/project/my-project-id/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk
        var serviceAccount = { ... content of json service account file ... };

        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library
        var header = {
            "alg": "RS256",
            "typ": "JWT"
        };

        var seconds = Math.trunc(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
        var payload = {
            iss : serviceAccount.client_email,
            sub : serviceAccount.client_email,
            aud : "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
            iat : seconds,
            exp : seconds + (60*60), // Maximum expiration time is one hour
            uid : uid,
            claims : {
                premium_account : false
            }
        };

        // https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/blob/master/src/JWT.php#L156
        var segments = [];

        segments.push(base64url(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(header))));
        segments.push(base64url(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(payload))));

        var signingInput = segments.join(".");
        var secret = serviceAccount.private_key
                    .replace('-----END PRIVATE KEY-----', '') // remove head
                    .replace('-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----', '') // remove tail
                    .replace(/\n/g, ''); // remove all new-line chars

        segments.push(base64url(CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(signingInput, secret)));
        return segments.join(".");
    }

    /**
    * https://codepen.io/jpetitcolas/pen/zxGxKN
    */
    function base64url(source) {
        // Encode in classical base64
        var encodedSource = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(source);

        // Remove padding equal characters
        encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/=+$/, '');

        // Replace characters according to base64url specifications
        encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/\+/g, '-');
        encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/\//g, '_');

        return encodedSource;
    }

    function firebaseLogin(customToken) {
        // FIXME omitted code, firebase initialize

        firebase
            .auth()
            .signInWithCustomToken(customToken)
            .then(function(response) {
                alert("Success signInWithCustomToken");
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                alert("signInWithCustomToken ERROR\n" + error.code + "\n" + error.message);
            });
    }
})();
```

I followed different examples I found (I linked them in the code) and the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library) for using custom clients.

I read the code many times and all seems to be ok, but for the given error I think I'm missing something very easy that I'm unable to see while generating the jwt token.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyCustomToken?key=xxx-my-api-key-xxx
{"token":"xxx-generated-custom-token-xxx","returnSecureToken":true}

HTTP RESPONSE 400 
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As a TamperMonkey this is meant to run directy inside the browser, no Node environment or others are available, this is why I'm using "raw" libraries instead of more integrated one.

Do you see any mistake when generating the jwt token?

Answer (score 1):

Solved with the use of [jsrsasign](https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/wiki/Tutorial-for-JWT-generation) (It is one of the JS libs suggested by https://jwt.io/ website).
I still don't know which the problem is, I think something relating to parsing the secret key. Most of code is now managed by the library so the flow is working properly.

Here is updated code related to token generation:

Add to script header:

```
 // @require      https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsrsasign/8.0.12/jsrsasign-all-min.js
```

And the function to create jwt

```
    var serviceAccount = { ... content of json service account file ... };

    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library
    var header = {
        "alg": "RS256",
        "typ": "JWT"
    };

    var payload = {
        iss : serviceAccount.client_email,
        sub : serviceAccount.client_email,
        aud : "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
        iat : KJUR.jws.IntDate.get('now'),
        exp : KJUR.jws.IntDate.get('now + 1hour'),
        uid : uid
    };

    // https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/wiki/Tutorial-for-JWT-generation
    var sHeader = JSON.stringify(header);
    var sPayload = JSON.stringify(payload);

    var prvKey = KEYUTIL.getKey(serviceAccount.private_key);
    var sJWT = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign("RS256", sHeader, sPayload, prvKey);

    return sJWT;
```